# Get All Controls in a Panel from Up-to-Down

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am writing a code to get all the controls in a panel , Like :

```
       foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(c.Name.ToString());
        }
```

It is right and return me all the Controls .
The TabIndex for the Top control (textBox1) is 0 and it increase from up-to-down (it means that textBox2 is below the textBox1 and textBox2's TabIndex is 1 .)

When I run this code in MessageBox it return me textBox2 at first , then textBox1 !

So , What is the base for this select ( Why does the computer select textbox2 at first) ?

How can I solve this problem ?!

thank u

Comment: It depends on how you added them in design time

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio's WinForms Designer to create your Form? If so, VS will auto generate the code for the Controls and it could be that `textBox1` is added after `textBox2`, which obviously results in the `textBox2` returning first on iteration. Also, by doing a bit of research you could've read about [Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is just the list of controls ordered by the TabIndex.
The Controls property gets you the controls list in the order they were added to your form.
You just have to sort that list by the TabIndex.

```
Using System.Linq;

foreach (var item in panel1.Controls.OfType<Control>().OrderBy(ee=>ee.TabIndex))
```

Comment: Your code two errors : 

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery' And ||||

'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.OfType<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can also order by the location of the Controls.  By getting the points.

It returns the text box you added first to the Control from top to down.

Comment: It is not related with their *locations*